# Forward output from Docker container while provisioning vm with Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant

Is there any option to see the output from Vagrant's Docker provisioner running a container?

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "barge"
  config.vm.box = "ailispaw/barge"

  config.vm.provision :docker do |d|
    d.run "hello-world",
      image: "hello-world",
      daemonize: false,
      restart: 'no',
      verbosity: 'vvv' <<< DOESN'T WORK AS WITH ANSIBLE :(
  end
end
```

Running

> vagrant provision --debug

gives no real output from hello-world container:

```
 INFO interface: info: Starting Docker containers...
 INFO interface: info: ==> barge: Starting Docker containers...
==> barge: Starting Docker containers...
 INFO interface: info: -- Container: hello-world
 INFO interface: info: ==> barge: -- Container: hello-world
==> barge: -- Container: hello-world
 INFO ssh: Execute: mkdir -p /var/lib/vagrant/cids (sudo=true)
 INFO ssh: Execute: sudo docker ps -q -a --no-trunc | grep -wFq $(cat /var/lib/vagrant/cids/fbb969117edfa916b86dfb67fd11decf1e336df0) (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Execute: docker inspect --format='{{.Image}}' hello-world | grep $(docker images -q hello-world) (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Execute: sudo docker ps -q --no-trunc | grep -wFq $(cat /var/lib/vagrant/cids/fbb969117edfa916b86dfb67fd11decf1e336df0) (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Execute: docker start $(cat /var/lib/vagrant/cids/fbb969117edfa916b86dfb67fd11decf1e336df0) (sudo=true)
```